# Rails view: if params[:search] display h1 else h1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I am performing a query on a model and wanted to display in index.html.erb different h1 based on action.
I have this very simple if statement:

```
 <% if params[:search] %>
<%= <h1>Search Results</h1> %>
<% else %>
<%= <h1>Listing bboys</h1> %>
<% end %>
```

Error log is:

```
SyntaxError in Bboys#index

Showing /home/ggeorgiev/projects/projects/bboyratings/app/views/bboys/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

/home/ggeorgiev/projects/projects/bboyratings/app/views/bboys/index.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected '<'
@output_buffer.append=( <h1>Search Results</h1> );@out...
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use the `<% %>` \ `<%= %>` Syntax if you want to use Ruby Code. Not for normal HTML.

```
<% if params[:search] %>
  <h1>Search Results</h1>
<% else %>
  <h1>Listing bboys</h1>
<% end %>
```